# Github error "File could not be edited"

Tags: github

Getting the error "File could not be edited" when I try to commit on one of my repositories on GitHub. Have tried clearing cookies/cache and using another browser but have had no luck.

Is this an issue with GitHub or is it something I can fix?

Comment: Can you post the exact commands you are running and the output? Are you getting the problem when commiting or when pushing to Github?

Comment: @HaraldNordgren I'm currently commiting to a .html file through the website itself. I just tested and only get this error on one repository, the others work like normal.

Comment: Ok, so probably some problem with the write access on this particular repo or file.